# How to detect the signal when there is a collision between two ClutterActors?

Tags: c++, 2d-games, clutter

I'd like to detect the point of collision of two ClutterActors using g_signal_connect.

I need some event to detect it similar to "enter-event"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clutter by itself does not handle hit testing between actors.

you want to use clutter-box2d, which allows the Box2D physics engine to drive a Clutter scene graph: https://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter-box2d